# Bitwise operations with CGBitmapInfo and CGImageAlphaInfo

Tags: swift, core-graphics, bit-manipulation

I'm having trouble performing bitwise operations with `CGImageAlphaInfo` and `CGBitmapInfo` in Swift.

In particular, I don't know how to port this Objective-C code:

```
bitmapInfo &= ~kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask;
bitmapInfo |= kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
```

The following straightforward Swift port produces the somewhat cryptic compiler error `'CGBitmapInfo' is not identical to 'Bool'` on the last line:

```
bitmapInfo &= ~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask
bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst
```

Looking at the source code I noticed that `CGBitmapInfo` is declared as a `RawOptionSetType` while `CGImageAlphaInfo` isn't. Maybe this has something to do with it?

It doesn't help that the official documentation on bitwise operators doesn't cover enums.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the right equivalent Swift code:

```
bitmapInfo &= ~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask
bitmapInfo |= CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
```

It's a little strange because `CGImageAlphaInfo` isn't actually a bitmask -- it's just a UInt32 `enum` (or a CF_ENUM/NS_ENUM with type `uint32_t`, in C parlance), with values for 0 through 7.

What's actually happening is that your first line clears the first five bits of `bitmapInfo`, which *is* a bitmask (aka `RawOptionSetType` in Swift), since `CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask` is 31, or 0b11111. Then your second line sticks the raw value of the `CGImageAlphaInfo` enum into those cleared bits.

I haven't seen enums and bitmasks combined like this anywhere else, if that explains why there isn't really documentation. Since `CGImageAlphaInfo` is an enum, its values are mutually exclusive. This wouldn't make any sense:

```
bitmapInfo &= ~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask
bitmapInfo |= CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
bitmapInfo |= CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
```

Comment: This changed again in swift 2.0 which now uses OptionSetTypeProtocol. Use now `var bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: ~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)`

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 3, Xcode 8 Beta 5, the syntax (as JackPearse pointed out, it conforms to OptionSetType protocol) is changed again and we no longer need `~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue`, instead we just use

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue)
```

You can add other bitmap info settings via the `|` operator, e.g.

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `CGImageAlphaInfo` values need to be converted to `CGBitmapInfo` in order to perform bitwise operations. This can be done like this:

```
bitmapInfo &= ~CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask
bitmapInfo |= CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
```